# How to delete property from spread operator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to delete drugName from the response but it is not happening any idea how to delete property from spread operator ?
main.js

```
  const transformedResponse = transformResponse(response);
  const loggerResponse = {...transformedResponse};
  delete loggerResponse[drugName];
  console.log("LOGGER>>>>", loggerResponse);
  logger().info('Drug Price Response=', { ...loggerResponse, memberId: memberId, pharmacyId: pharmacyId });
```

\
data

```
LOGGER>>>> {
    '0': {
        isBrand: false,
        drugName: 'test drug',
        drugStrength: '5 mg 1 5 mg',
        drugForm: 'Tablet',
    }
}
```

transformResponse

```
[{
    drugName: 'HYDROCODONE-HOMATROPINE MBR',
    drugStrength: '5MG-1.5MG',
    drugForm: 'TABLET',
    brand: false
}]
```

Comment: There is no `drugName` variable in your code. If you want to remove `drugName`, then `delete loggerResponse.drugName`?

Comment: @adiga i tried that it did not remove i added the data how it is coming from service

Comment: Please post a sample of `transformedResponse`. Is it an array? Because, there is a `0` key in `loggerResponse`

Comment: @adiga yes it is an array i added to the question

Comment: What is your expected output? Will `transformedResponse` always have one item?

Comment: it could have multiple items thats why its an array

Comment: Should `loggerResponse` be an array of objects with one less property in each object? It's still unclear why you're spreading the array inside `{}`

Comment: thats correct it should be array of objects without the drugname

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You could use [Rest syntax in Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to get all the properties except `drugName` to a `rest` variable like this:

```js
const transformedResponse = [{
    drugName: 'HYDROCODONE-HOMATROPINE MBR',
    drugStrength: '5MG-1.5MG',
    drugForm: 'TABLET',
    brand: false
},
{
    drugName: 'HYDROCODONE ABC',
    drugStrength: '10MG',
    drugForm: 'SYRUP',
    brand: true
}]

const output = transformedResponse.map(({ drugName, ...rest }) => rest)

console.log(output)
```

Also, when you spread an array inside `{}`, you get an object with indices of the array as key and the values of array as value. This is why you get an object with `0` as key in `loggerResponse`:

```js
const array = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]
console.log({ ...array })
```

Comment: I think "rest pattern" is a useful way to distinguish `...rest` as it is used here from "rest parameters" and "spread arguments". Nice and clean answer.

Comment: @adiga is it possibel to destruct multiple properties like {drugName,drugForm, ...rest} , i tried it its only remving drugName

Comment: @hussain that should work: `transformedResponse.map(({ drugName, drugForm, ...rest }) => rest)` Check the casing of properties.

Comment: ` "drugPrice": [
        {
            "isBrand": true,
            "drugName": "Lipitor",
            "drugStrength": "80 mg",
            "drugForm": "Tablet",
            "mailPrice": {
                "copayEmployer": 0}}]` ok i was trying to delete mailPrice.copayEmployer actually and that is not being deleted it is nested object

Comment: @hussain for that, you'd have to destructure the nested property separately. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/c8n2fu4a/1/. You can destructure the parameter itself, or, If it is too confusing, you can take separate variables inside `map`

Comment: @adiga i really appreciate help here if we have another object at same level as mailPrice and that has similar property , Can we do this `const loggerResponse = transformedResponse.map(({ drugName, mailPrice,retailPrice, ...rest  }) => {
    const { copayEmployer, ...mailPriceRest } = mailPrice;
    const { copayEmployer, ...retailPriceRest } = retailPrice;
    return { ...rest, mailPrice: mailPriceRest , retailPrice: retailPriceRest};
  })` i tried and it says blocked scope variable can not redeclared

Comment: @hussain that's because now you have 2 variables named `const copayEmployer` inside `map`'s callback. You can [rename the variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) to something else to avoid this conflict. `const { copayEmployer : _, ...retailPriceRest } = retailPrice;` This is same as `const _ = retailPrice.copayEmployer`

Comment: @hussain please go through the [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) MDN link thoroughly once. It is basically creating variables with same name as the property and assigning value of that property. Once you get the gist of it, it seems really easy.

Comment: @adiga But if you have two objects that have similar properties how it would remove because mailPrice and retailPrice both have copayEmployer that I wanted to delete. Changing variable would not work right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193492/discussion-between-adiga-and-hussain).

Answer (score 89):

### 1 line solution using ES9 Object Rest Operator

```js
const loggerResponse = {
  "0": {
    isBrand: false,
    drugName: "test drug",
    drugStrength: "5 mg 1 5 mg",
    drugForm: "Tablet",
  },
};
const { drugName, ...newResponse } = loggerResponse["0"];
console.log(newResponse);
```

Comment: upvote for one liner and teaching me something new, thanks!

Comment: is there a way to do this inside another object ?

Comment: Problem with this is linting, in our project at work the project fails to build given I'm not using drugName

Answer (score 37):

```js
const myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
const {
  b,
  ...noB // assigns remaining keys to a new `noB` object
} = myObject;
console.log(noB); // => { a: 1, c: 3 }
```

Comment: It would help if you would explain shy your code would solve this issue. In other words add some comments so we can understand what your code does...

Comment: it is only a few line js code. i think it doesn't need any explain. Just should try.

Comment: @Klaasiek - pretty straight forward - he destructures the original object into two objects: one containing the unwanted key, and one containing the remaining keys.  Then, he uses the one containing the remaining keys.  pretty concise code.

Comment: Shouldn't it be named `noB`?

Comment: Keep in mind, due to the wild fun of JavaScript, that this won't do a deep copy.  Meaning if you use this method, and myObject gets a mutation (e.g. a sub-object such as myObject.d.moreStuff changes later), the `noB` object would be changed also.  Lodash's omit may have a way around it (and if it doesn't you could use a lodash cloneDeep beforehand to mitigate). Buyer beware :)

Comment: brilliant and elegant solution!

Answer (score 30):

Another option is to write a generic function, `removeKey` -

```js
const removeKey = (k, { [k]:_, ...o }) =>
  o

const values =
  [ { a: 1, x: 1 }
  , { a: 1, y: 1 }
  , { a: 1, z: 1 }
  ]

console .log (values .map (v => removeKey ("a", v)))
// [ { x: 1 }, { y: 1 }, { z: 1 } ]
```

The function can be easily adapted to remove multiple keys, if necessary -

```js
const removeKey = (k = "", { [k]:_, ...o } = {}) =>
  o

const removeKeys = (keys = [], o = {}) =>
  keys .reduce ((r, k) => removeKey (k, r), o)

const values =
  [ { a: 1, x: 1 }
  , { a: 1, y: 1 }
  , { a: 1, z: 1 }
  ]

console .log (values .map (v => removeKeys (['a', 'z'], v)))
// [ { x: 1 }, { y: 1 }, {} ]
```

Comment: Amazing answer, wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: Thanks, removeKey is short and usable for removing variable keys

Answer (score 12):

Another one line solution will be,

```
return {...(delete obj.del && obj)}
```

Comment: I like this because of the "delete" keyword, it's not doing weird javascript mysterious syntax stuff.

Comment: The only problem to be aware of with this is that if you passed `obj` as a parameter to the function, upon return that property will be deleted for the caller as well.  You'd have to make a copy of `obj` first and then delete from the copy to solve this issue: `let copy = {...obj}; delete copy.del; return {...copy};`

Comment: @Malvineous, curious, why also spread the return?

Comment: That was just meant as a placeholder so you could add additional properties as the OP was doing: `return {...copy, extraValue: 'example'};`.  If you are not adding extra values then `return copy;` would be fine, or you could add your extra values in the `let copy` assignment instead.  Sorry for the confusion, it is a bit unnecessary having two spread operators there.

Answer (score 8):

This is the most succinct and immutable way that I've found. You simply destructure the object into two parts: one part is the property you're trying to remove (`drugName` in this case), and the other part is the rest of the object, that you want to keep (`drugWithoutName` in this case).

Once you've done that, you can abandon the property that has been removed, abandon the original object, and use the new object (`drugWithoutName` in this case) that has all of the remaining fields.

Coming up with the syntax isn't obvious, but it makes sense once you see it:

```js
const response = [{
    drugName: 'HYDROCODONE-HOMATROPINE MBR',
    drugStrength: '5MG-1.5MG',
    drugForm: 'TABLET',
    brand: false
}]

console.log("response", response)

const removeNamesFromResponse = (response) => {
  return response.map(drug => {
    const { drugName, ...drugWithoutName } = drug
    return drugWithoutName
  })
}

const responseWithoutNames = removeNamesFromResponse(response)

console.log("responseWithoutNames", responseWithoutNames)
```

These articles explain the concept further:

https://codeburst.io/use-es2015-object-rest-operator-to-omit-properties-38a3ecffe90

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/README.md#objects--rest-spread

Comment: Except linting fails because drugName is never referenced

Comment: @StephenYork This is a part of a larger app. If `drugName` makes your linting fail because it's unused in your use case, you should be able to use some name like `_` that is acceptable to the linter as a name for a variable that is intentionally unused.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the spread operator and simply assigning `undefined` to the key you don't want:

```js
const transformedResponse = [{
drugName: 'HYDROCODONE-HOMATROPINE MBR',
drugStrength: '5MG-1.5MG',
drugForm: 'TABLET',
brand: false
}];

const output = transformedResponse.map((response) => ({
  ...response,
  drugName: undefined
}))

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Close but not quite there, HEADS UP!, 
if we use if(drugname in output) will result true, you need to compare the VALUE, drugName key will still exist!

Answer (score 0):

If you have property `drugName` in every object of `transformedResponse` array you can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate a new array without `drugName` property:

**Example:**

```js
const transformedResponse = [
  {
    drugName: 'HYDROCODONE-HOMATROPINE MBR',
    drugStrength: '5MG-1.5MG',
    drugForm: 'TABLET',
    brand: false
  },
  {
    drugName: 'TEST',
    drugStrength: '7MG-1.9MG',
    drugForm: 'TABLET',
    brand: false
  }
];

const loggerResponse = transformedResponse.map(o =>
{
    let clone = Object.assign({}, o);
    return (delete clone.drugName, clone);
});

console.log(loggerResponse);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Problem with this is linting, in our project at work the project fails
> to build given I'm not using drugNamestrong text

/*eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "ignoreRestSiblings": true }]*/
// 'drugName' is ignored because it has a rest property sibling.

const output = transformedResponse.map(({ drugName, ...rest }) => rest)

console.log(output)
[Ref](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars#ignorerestsiblings)