# TypeScript with the Rest Operator binding element x implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript

I have the following line of TypeScript code:

```
const removeType = ({ type, ...rest }) => rest;
```

It is a function that removes the `type` property from the passed in `rest` object. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56156100/613605).

I am getting the following error:

> Binding element 'type' implicitly has an 'any' type.

How do I get rid of the error? It might be a linting error, but I'd like to get rid of it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type it as follows:

```
const removeType = <T extends { type: unknown }>({ type, ...rest }: T) => rest;
```

so now:

```
const x = removeType({ type: 1, somethingElse: "hello" })

console.log(x.somethingElse);
// console.log(x.type) // error!
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwLYgG4ICoE8AOCYC8MAPBjAgB5QJgAmEMA3jFLggFwwCuYA1mCADuYGAF8AfAApmrPABoYAOmWJoYzhgCUhcfATQA3ACgjoSLAqE9KdNjzSWbTgEYFEEEgRQAFgEswAOYAogA2EBwwAETeCCEhIJFimiZm7iEIivEBkhSK7p4+-sFhCJrGAPTlMKkg6Zkg2bmypTCV5HBwIHAAhEA)

Answer (score 1):

You can also infer the type of rest obj

```js
const removeType = <Rest,>({ type, ...rest }: { type: unknown } & Rest) => rest;

const x = removeType({ type: 'div', name: 'John' })
x.name // ok
x.type // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFGMHsDsGcBcAEAnApgW0gN1QFQJ4AOqiAvIgDwBKqCANAHwAUA3ovEanYgHR9oJEAXwBciNh2JiArtADW0SAHdowxADJENBAEoyDFLXgBuUBBiCAHmUOYcBYq3acxAcgAmASyyvu0AIboqG4AUpAAFtCuwjqgljwBQYgA9MmIkHJxPJIkqYioyMiQyKBAA)

Here you have generic proper typed solution:

```js
const removeProperty = <Obj, Prop extends keyof Obj>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop) => {
  const { [prop]: _, ...rest } = obj;
  return rest
}
```

Hover the mouse on function name, you will se the type of return value:`Omit<Obj, Prop>`

More examples you can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/FP-style#fp_utils)